# Is it possible to prefill a form using ng-model in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form

```
 <form>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="edit"><br />
  </form>
```

and a simple array in the controller

```
$scope.statuses = [
    {value: 1, text: 'status1'},
    {value: 2, text: 'status2'},
    {value: 3, text: 'status3'},
    {value: 4, text: 'status4'}
  ];
```

I am repeating the array in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="x in statuses">{{x.text}}<button ng-model="edit">edit</button></div>
```

so i was wondering when i click the edit button can the data be populated inside the form input field using ng-model ? 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VT1VSPsl7sbjuq3pOb3y?p=preview)

Comment: Why have you put ng-model="edit" in your button when it is already in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using a `ng-click` in yout button instead of a `ng-model`.

Your button will have to run a function on click, just like this :

```
<button ng-click="editFunction(x)">edit</button>
```

And then in your controller, there is the function :

```
$scope.editFunction = function(x){
   $scope.edit = x.text;
}
```

In this function you will get the value of x and set this value in your form `ng-model`.

There is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CV9Zn5DdLgtzGr8FaOH8?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer